# Using s3a to fetch spark jars in driver and executor

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, mesos

I'm trying to use Spark on AWS using the driver/executor model. There doesn't seem to be a way to set the driver classpath such that it can use the hadoop-aws jar plus the aws-sdk jar to get access to s3. I want to pull my job jars from s3.

Seems like I either need to add all these classes to the spark assembly jar, or I need to modify the spark-class script to add these jars to the classpath manually?

Are there any less intrusive methods, i.e. any way to just specify this in config somewhere?

I'm running 1.6.1 and hadoop 2.4, but I expect I can use 2.6 too (same problem).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but you should be able to set the `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and/or the `spark.driver.extraLibraryPath` property according to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)

IMHO, the same thing should be achievable by specifying the `--jars` command-line option when using `spark-submit`, see the [help output](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-submit.html) from `spark-submit`.